# Different query plan between two queries when only change is using variable

Tags: sql-server

I have one query which is very fast:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA
        LEFT JOIN
    TableB
        INNER JOIN
    TableC
        INNER JOIN
    TableD
        LEFT JOIN
    TableE
WHERE
    TableA.Date >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))) AND TableA.Date < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

But if I use variable dates in the `WHERE` clause that are the same value as the `WHERE` clause in the first query, the query is extraordinarily much slower. This was brought to my attention as someone was trying to optimize the query, but I don't understand why this one would take longer. It's essentially the same query, no?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME; 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT
    @StartDate = DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))

SELECT
    @EndDate = GETDATE()

SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA
        LEFT JOIN
    TableB
        INNER JOIN
    TableC
        INNER JOIN
    TableD
        LEFT JOIN
    TableE
WHERE
    TableA.Date >= @StartDate AND TableA.Date < EndDate
```

Looking at the query plans, there seems to be no parallelism implemented with the variables being used. Why would that be?

Comment: Not the problem, but note that your first query is using `date` and the second is using `datetime`.

Comment: The queries aren't the same as use you date in one and datetime in the other.  Depending on the values in your table (and, more specifically, their data types) the second query may be having to convert values.  Can you add the query plans?

Comment: Another major issue is the CONVERT AND GETDATE function in the where clause.  Any function in the where clause prevents SQL from using an index.  The >= though allows the optimizer to use an index seek if that date column is indexed.

Comment: @RobertSievers, you can absolutely get a seek in this case. "No functions in the where clause" applies to functions on *columns*. And you can get a seek even with the convert, in this case at least.

Comment: @RobertSievers the query using the functions was much faster

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I apologize for any confusion I may have caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality estimates are going to be different. The effects many choices in the execution plan, which can lead to different performance. The reason is that the first query isn't being parameterized. The second one is.

Get the estimate execution plan for these:

```
SELECT 1
FROM TableA
WHERE Date >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())))
      AND Date < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());


DECLARE @StartDate DATE= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())));
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());

SELECT 1
FROM TableA
WHERE Date >= @StartDate
      AND Date < @EndDate;
```

You'll probably see a different estimated row count coming from TableA. If you prefer this query pattern, you can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM TableA
WHERE Date >= @StartDate
      AND Date < @EndDate
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: They are certainly different, I don't understand why they would be though when the variable values are equivalent to the function calls in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: To the cardinality estimator, `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are *any* date. It's making a wild guess. Set both to `GETDATE()` and you'll get the same estimate. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` forces SQL Server to consider the actual values of `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`.

Comment: It's called [parameter sniffing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/).